# Where does Docker invoiceninja/invoiceninja store data?

Tags: invoice-ninja

The [invoiceninja/invoiceninja](https://hub.docker.com/r/invoiceninja/invoiceninja/) Dockerfile seems to not have any dependency on a database. How/where are the data going to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

it needs running MySQL and storage folder.

read more:
https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles